# Integration by partial fractions problem

Tags: integration, partial-fractions

[image]

I'm having a lot of trouble with this integral. I don't know what to set A+B equal to. There's an x^4 in the numerator and I'm trying to figure out how to account for it. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Problem: $$\int\frac{x^4}{4-x^2}\space dx$$

What I have tried:

$$\frac{x^4}{(2-x)(2+x)}=\frac{a}{2-x}+\frac{b}{2+x}=\frac{a(2+x)+b(2-x)}{(2-x)(2+x)}\implies x^4=(a+b)x+2(a+b)$$

Comment: First of all, do not present the problem in this way.  Instead, **learn mathjax** and present the problem accordingly.  Second of all, in order to use partial fractions it is best to reduce $\frac{x^4}{4-x^2}$ to a **proper fraction.  This means: divide $x^4$ by $4-x^2.$  The quotient will be easy to integrate and you will then apply partial fractions to the remainder.**  Third of all, if you are still having problems, **show significant work in your query,** and elaborate on exactly where you are still having problems.

Answer (score 3):

When the numerator has higher degree, you should do long division before partial fractions.

$$\frac{x^4}{4-x^2} = -x^2 - 4 - \frac{16}{x^2-4}.$$
Now you can do partial fractions on the last term.

Comment: Oh wow I knew that. Just escaped me for a second. Thank you.